# Using Excel to open latest version of a File (with different name)

Tags: excel, macros, timestamp, vba

I need to create a macro to open another excel file (so I can copy the contents). this file is regularly refreshed and I need take the data from the latest version of this file. Each file has a variation in the name as the latest version has an larger version number (not incremental). They will also have a date which I need to factor in.

Here is an example of the files.

Saved 16/03/2016 at 4.58pm

"Daily Global Model Extract_GL_FM_2016_03_16_165819.xls"

Saved 16/03/2016 at 5.58pm

"Daily Global Model Extract_GL_FM_2016_03_16_174817.xls"

I need something robust which will deal with the change in document name.

Comment: I don't see version numbers in your examples, but for the dates, just download the file names and sort them.  If you run into problems with your code, post it and ask the specific questions.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try.

```
Private Sub GetMostRecentFile()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Dim myFolder As Variant
    Dim myFileName As String
    Dim myFileDate As Date
    Dim myPartialLen As Integer

    myFilePath = "your folder path to search"
    myFileFindName = "Daily Global Model Extract"

    myDir = myFilePath

    If Right(myDir, 1) <> "\" Then
        myDir = myDir & "\"
    End If

    Set myFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set myFolder = myFSO.getfolder(myDir)

    myPartialLen = Len(myFileFindName)

    myFileDate = DateSerial(1900, 1, 1)
    For Each myFileObject In myFolder.Files
        x = Left(myFileObject.Name, myPartialLen)
        If x = myFileFindName Then
            Y = myFileObject.DateCreated
            If Y > myFileDate Then
                myFileDate = myFileObject.DateCreated
                myFileName = myFileObject.Name
            End If
        End If
    Next myFileObject
    If myFileName <> "" Then
        Workbooks.Open(myDir & myFileName)
        myMessage = "Opened file from " & myFileDate & "."
    Else
        myMessage = "Sorry, No files were found in this location."
    End If
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    MsgBox myMessage, vbOKOnly, "Most Recent File"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Zach, I found this which seems to work great

'Force the explicit delcaration of variables
Option Explicit

Sub OpenLatestFile()

```
'Declare the variables
Dim MyPath As String
Dim MyFile As String
Dim LatestFile As String
Dim LatestDate As Date
Dim LMD As Date

'Specify the path to the folder
MyPath = "C:\Users\Domenic\Documents\"

'Make sure that the path ends in a backslash
If Right(MyPath, 1) <> "\" Then MyPath = MyPath & "\"

'Get the first Excel file from the folder
MyFile = Dir(MyPath & "*.xls", vbNormal)

'If no files were found, exit the sub
If Len(MyFile) = 0 Then
    MsgBox "No files were found...", vbExclamation
    Exit Sub
End If

'Loop through each Excel file in the folder
Do While Len(MyFile) > 0

    'Assign the date/time of the current file to a variable
    LMD = FileDateTime(MyPath & MyFile)

    'If the date/time of the current file is greater than the latest
    'recorded date, assign its filename and date/time to variables
    If LMD > LatestDate Then
        LatestFile = MyFile
        LatestDate = LMD
    End If

    'Get the next Excel file from the folder
    MyFile = Dir

Loop

'Open the latest file
Workbooks.Open MyPath & LatestFile
```

End Sub